# How can I drop nan(s)?

Tags: python, pandas

Unique values of the column as follows:

```
array(['..', '0', nan, ..., '30.0378539547197', '73.3261637778593',
       '59.9402466154723'], dtype=object)
```

I use the following codes to drop NaNs and None.

```
df[df["Country Name"].isin([None]) == False]
```

and it still includes the NaNs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use "dropna" method if the NaN's are in a correct format.

And if you want to do it for a particular column then, use

`df["column_name"].dropna()`

or

`df.dropna(subset=['column_name1', 'column_name2'])`

I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this `df = df.dropna()` ?

Comment: But I would like to drop NaNs for a certain column